# Is it possible to like a comment with facebook graph api?

Tags: json, facebook-graph-api

I am reading in someone who I am friends with feed and trying to like one of thier comments using the ID/Likes graph api call however I am getting a 400 bad request. After looking at the object in the JSON feed there is no "likes" connection or an actions array on the comment. Why would this be when I know there are likes on this comment when looking through facebooks front end?

Comment: Do you have an `access_token` with `publish_stream` permissions? Is the post visible if you make a call to `/POST_ID`? If not, it is possible that the post is private or the user has blocked app access to their profile. If those aren't it, please post some code.

Comment: Yes I have the access token with publish stream permissions. I can even like this same persons standard wall posts so I know my code to like objects is working correctly. Looking deeper into the exception I am getting this oauth response back "(100) Error finding the requested story" when trying to like one of their comments. I know the objectID of the comment is correct also b/c that same objectID is in my feed JSON where I am getting the comment info. Not sure if there is still some sort of permissions issue with trying to like a comment someone posts vs liking a wall post a user posts?